# How write unit test for my gps interactor class?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

*This class work fine and now i am interesting how write unit test*

I have two independent flows:

- location
- gps status

I use **publish subject** for make my interactor in reactive manner.
Both flows mix with function **Observable.withLatestFrom** where i additionally add filtration and transformation.

Is it my gps class written correct ?

Can this class be tested ?

I need to test **initFullLocationObservable**

```
class GpsInteractor @Inject constructor(
        private val locationManager: LocationManager,
        private val googleApiClient: GoogleApiClient,
        private val locationRequest: LocationRequest): GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {

        private var gpsStatus: GpsStatus? = null
        val locationSubject = PublishSubject.create<LocationModel>()
        val satellitesSubject = PublishSubject.create<List<SatelliteModel>>()
        lateinit var fullLocationObservable: Observable<FullLocation> private set

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        fun callLocationUpdates(updateInterval: Int, smallestDisplacement: Int, minAccuracy: Int, minSatellitesCount: Int, minSnr: Int) {
            locationRequest.interval = (updateInterval * 1000).toLong()
            locationRequest.fastestInterval = (updateInterval * 1000).toLong()
            locationRequest.smallestDisplacement = smallestDisplacement.toFloat()
            locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

            googleApiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(this)
            locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this)

            fullLocationObservable = initFullLocationObservable(minAccuracy, minSatellitesCount, minSnr)
            googleApiClient.connect()
        }

        fun removeLocationUpdates() {
            locationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(this)
            if (googleApiClient.isConnected) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this)
                googleApiClient.disconnect()
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onConnected(p0: Bundle?) {  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this)
        }  

        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
            // TODO: make locationModel reusable
            locationSubject.onNext(LocationModel(latitude = location.latitude, longitude = location.longitude,
                time = location.time, speed = location.speed, accuracy = location.accuracy,
                altitude = location.altitude, bearing = location.bearing))
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onGpsStatusChanged(event: Int) {
            if (event != GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS) {
                return
            }
            gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(gpsStatus)
            if (gpsStatus != null) {
                // TODO: make satellitesModel reusable
                val satellites: List<SatelliteModel> = gpsStatus!!
                    .satellites.filter { it.usedInFix() }
                    .map { SatelliteModel(it.prn, it.elevation, it.azimuth, it.snr) }
                satellitesSubject.onNext(satellites)
            }
        }

        private fun initFullLocationObservable(minAccuracy: Int, minSatellitesCount: Int, minSnr: Int): Observable<FullLocation> {
            val locationObservable = locationSubject
                .filter { locationModel -> locationModel.accuracy <= minAccuracy }

            val satellitesObservable = satellitesSubject
                .map { satellites: List<SatelliteModel> ->
                    satellites.filter { it.snr  >= minSnr }
                }
                .filter { it.size >= minSatellitesCount }

            return locationObservable.withLatestFrom(satellitesObservable, BiFunction { locationModel: LocationModel, satellitesModel: List<SatelliteModel> ->
                val locationData = LocationData(locationModel)
                val satellites = satellitesModel.map { Satellite(it.snr, locationData) }
                FullLocation(locationData, satellites)
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself is what do you want to test? Testing only for testing is worthless. Way of writing tests is quite simple and I am almost sure you know it (prepare, execute, check). The code you published looks a good code, I mean there is no static dependencies there, so it's seems to be a something good for testing, but, like I said - the question is what you want to test.